# Generics - method cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, generics

I am going through the book Java Generics and Collections and came across an example which I don't understand.

```java
// Original example in book
public static <T, C extends Collection<T>> C copy(C coll) throws InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        C copy = newInstance(coll);
        copy.addAll(coll);
        return copy;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add("something");
        copy(l);
}
```

What I don't understand is why do we need two type parameters in the `copy` method. If I change the definition of the method to below, the compiler complains with an error

```java
// changed method definition
public static <C extends Collection<C>> C copy(C coll) throws InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        C copy = newInstance(coll);
        copy.addAll(coll);
        return copy;
}
```

compiler error:

```
Error:(44, 26) java: method copy in class  cannot be applied to given types;
  required: C
  found: java.util.List<java.lang.String>
  reason: inference variable C has incompatible bounds
    upper bounds: java.util.Collection<C>
    equality constraints: java.lang.String
```

Based on my understanding of Generics, in the changed example `C=List<String>` and `List<String> extends Collection<String>`, so why does the above code not work ? Is it not something similar to `T extends Comparable<T>`

Comment: It is correct that `C=List<String>` and `List<String> extends Collection<String>`, but your method requires `C extends Collection<C>`, in other words `List<String> extends Collection<List<String>>`, which is *clearly* not true.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. If possible, could you also please shed some light on how T is inferred by the compiler to be String in such a case.

Comment: What kind of explanation are you expecting? The whole type inference algorithm is specified in [Chapter 18 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-18.html). You can just go through that step by step if you want.

Comment: As an aside which `newInstance` method is that?

Comment: In other words: `T` is the element type, so `String` in your example. `C` is the collection type, here `List`. They cannot be the same, you need both (or you could not specify that a `List<String>` is also returned).. And when you pass something declared as a `List<String>`, from that the compiler can infer both.

Comment: `C extends Collection<?>` might work.  Not `C extends Collection<C>`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Then the compiler would not know that the returned collection has the same element type as the one in the argument. Would probably be nice to know in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't understand is why do we need two type parameters in the copy method. If I change the definition of the method to below, the compiler complains with an error

```
// changed method definition
public static <C extends Collection<C>> C copy(C coll) throws InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        C copy = newInstance(coll);
        copy.addAll(coll);
        return copy;
}
```

Consider that `C extends Collection<C>` means that `C` is a subtype of `Collection<C>`.   For whatever type you imagine `C` to be (other than perhaps `Object`) could it ever be a subtype of a Collection of itself?  Could a `String` be a subtype of `Collection<String>` And as mentioned could a `List<String>` be a subtype of `Collection<List<String>>`.  Which again implies that `String` and `List<String>` are the same type.  The second parameter `T` provides for a new type which makes the subtyping work by separating `C` from `T`.